# How do I stop rules on submit if validation fails?

Tags: error, validation, submit, infopath-rules

I have multiple rules on my submit button, which I need to process only if the validation passes.  Currently if I have validation errors, the other rules run and change the views and the function on the form to that of an approver, thus confusing the originator.

Is there away to disable additional rules if the validation fails?  In other words do not run following rules if the condition of this rule is **not** met.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You could [add a hidden field](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2008/11/how-to-create-a-hidden-field-in-infopath/) that tracks whether a validation rule has failed, ie have it set to 0 on load and set it to 1 if a rule fails. Then on each validation rule add a condition so the rule only goes through if the hidden field is 0. This will make sure only one of your validation rules will go through.